# Use `this.$watch` instead of `$scope.$watch` with 'Controller As'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Currently I am using the `Controller As` format for scoping controllers.

This works great for keeping the scope of values on the views clear and easy to follow.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as myctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in myctrl.contacts">
            <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name.first" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, when implementing a `$watch` I am running into problems because it seems to be dependent on `$scope` so the following will not work.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController',['contacts',function(contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;

    this.$watch('contacts', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       console.log({older: oldValue, newer:newValue});
    });

}]);
```

I get **undefined is not a function** in reference to `this` not having a method `$watch`.

Is there a way to `$watch` a value with the `Controller As` format?

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/nogrp164/)**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even with the `controllerAs` format, the `$scope` is there.

In fact what `controllerAs` does is bind the controller instance's `this` to the $scope.
E.g. `controller="myController as myctrl"` does (behind the scenes): `$scope.myctrl = this` (where `this` refers to the `myController` instance).

So, you can just inject and use the `$scope` for watches:

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope, contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return contacts;
    }, function (newValue, oldValue) {...});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @ExpertSystem I had tried injecting the `$scope`, but I had tried `$scope.$watch(this.contacts, ...` and didn't realize the watched value needed returned in that format.

Comment: Help me understand http://plnkr.co/edit/mFugWfzT2bLGVxwJyBfT?p=preview . Cant see no alerts while changing value :(

Answer (score 4):

```
$scope.$watch("contact", callback, true) // true makes it a deep/recursive watch
```

Comment: The key is the third param: *true*, which makes a deep watch. I tried a lot but the callback function didn't fire ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
            return this.contacts;
        }), function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log((newValue + '  -  ' + oldValue));
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Additional explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Others written clearly about why $scope is generally still required. But not how to actually watch your variables in the case of your example to properly watch the local variable "contacts" you must identify it by the controller namespace.

So:

```
$scope.$watch('myctrl.contacts', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       console.log({older: oldValue, newer:newValue});
    });
```

The idea of using the local namespace is to prevent mutation if you create child controllers inside another controller. The nice benefit of this is that a parent controller can watch all the spaces inside its scope.

Lets say that the initial html looked something like:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as myctrl">
  <div ng-controller="listController as mylist">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in myctrl.contacts">
            <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name.first" />
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController',['$scope',function(contacts) {

    $scope.$watch('mylist.contacts', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       console.log({older: oldValue, newer:newValue});
    })
.controller('listController',['contacts',function(contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    });
}]);
```

Now the main controller is watching activity in a nested controller... pretty nifty.