# AngularJS $scope.$watch callback function parameter undefined in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have defined a `$scope.$watch` in my controller on a scope variable named `ctrl.test`. The $watch's callback function is called with the correct value (newVal) in a production deployment, but when called from a Jasmine test, it is called with `undefined`. 
Directly accessing the `ctrl.test` does yield the correct value.

Could anybody shed some light on this? Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YlGMxChdZNHRadtt1JIk?p=preview) to fiddle around with.

Comment: are there any errors on console?

Comment: No, just that the test failed because of the expectation (Expected undefined to equal 'test').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Controller As pattern, use a function as the watch expression.

Replace:

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.test', ...
```

With:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return ctrl.test;
}, ...
```

New plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/4tb4nhjtdRtv8cLURWZg?p=preview

More info about why this is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25748208/2943490

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you also have an explanation why it only fails when running unit tests? 
Shame it doesn't work, because I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` all over the place.

Comment: @Dormouse I found the reason. Problem is that 'vm' is not put on scope through controllerAs in a unit test as it would be in production (I think). Has a nice solution to a hairy problem http://juristr.com/blog/2014/11/learning-ng-testing-watch-expressions/

Comment: I had been struggling with this for way too long and this fixed my issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the best solution was to keep the watch like usually

```
$scope.$watch( 'myController.varToWatch', function(newVal,oldValue) {
    //blabla
});
```

and attach the controller scope to the property: **$scope.myController = myController;**

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_,_$rootScope_){
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
    myController = $controller('settingsController', { $scope: $scope });
    $scope.myController = myController;
}));
```

inspired from here : http://juristr.com/blog/2014/11/learning-ng-testing-watch-expressions/